# Recursive method to return a set of all combinations

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone explain me how this code works or if it is possible to be written in another way? I tried it with just ArrayList but cannot figure it out.

```
public static Set<Set<Integer>> combinations(List<Integer> groupSize, int k) {

    Set<Set<Integer>> allCombos = new HashSet<Set<Integer>> ();
    // base cases for recursion
    if (k == 0) {
        // There is only one combination of size 0, the empty team.
        allCombos.add(new HashSet<Integer>());
        return allCombos;
    }
    if (k > groupSize.size()) {
        // There can be no teams with size larger than the group size,
        // so return allCombos without putting any teams in it.
        return allCombos;
    }

    // Create a copy of the group with one item removed.
    List<Integer> groupWithoutX = new ArrayList<Integer> (groupSize);
    Integer x = groupWithoutX.remove(groupWithoutX.size()-1);

    Set<Set<Integer>> combosWithoutX = combinations(groupWithoutX, k);
    Set<Set<Integer>> combosWithX = combinations(groupWithoutX, k-1);
    for (Set<Integer> combo : combosWithX) {
        combo.add(x);
    }
    allCombos.addAll(combosWithoutX);
    allCombos.addAll(combosWithX);
    return allCombos;
}
```

Comment: What is the showTeam() method?

Comment: My mistake! its combinations() not showTeam()

Comment: You say "how this code works" -- is this some code you have to reuse? If you can use some external code and want to rely on it, I'd suggest using Guava's `Collections2`

Answer (score 2):

Basically the algorithm returns all subsets of `groupSize` (which should really be renamed to `group`), that have `k` elements.

The method works recursively. To do so it needs two things : establish primitive cases that end the recursion, and a way of formulating the problem in terms of itself, yet closer to the primitive form.

This algorithm has two primitive cases :

1. k == 0 : there is only one set that has 0 elements : the empty set.
2. k > size of the group : there are no subsets that have more elements than the original set

So there are two ways we can get to a primitive case : formulating it in terms of smaller sets (smaller group), or in terms of smaller subsets (smaller k)

The formulation in terms of itself for this algorithm is : given an element x from the group, its combinations are : `all subsets that contain x, and all subsets that do not contain x`.

- *All subsets that do not contain x*, is really all subsets of *the group without x* of size k (moves closer to second primitive case)
- *All subsets that contain x*, is all subsets of *the group without x* of size k-1 with x added to those subsets. (moves closer to both primitive cases)

The algorithm takes the last element of the group as x (but could just as well take another) : `Integer x = groupWithoutX.remove(groupWithoutX.size()-1);`

An example will make this clearer :

for `groupSize` = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and k = 3 the output would be

`[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]`

Picking the last element x = 5

this is

- all subsets of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` of size k = 3 : i.e. `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]`
- and all subsets of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` of size k = 2 and 5 added i.e. `[[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bowmores explanation I did some refactoring:

```
public static Set<Set<Integer>> getCombinationsFor(List<Integer> group, int subsetSize) {
    Set<Set<Integer>> resultingCombinations = new HashSet<Set<Integer>> ();
    int totalSize=group.size();
    if (subsetSize == 0) {
        emptySet(resultingCombinations);
    } else if (subsetSize <= totalSize) {
        List<Integer> remainingElements = new ArrayList<Integer> (group);
        Integer X = popLast(remainingElements);

        Set<Set<Integer>> combinationsExclusiveX = getCombinationsFor(remainingElements, subsetSize);
        Set<Set<Integer>> combinationsInclusiveX = getCombinationsFor(remainingElements, subsetSize-1);
        for (Set<Integer> combination : combinationsInclusiveX) {
            combination.add(X);
        }
        resultingCombinations.addAll(combinationsExclusiveX);
        resultingCombinations.addAll(combinationsInclusiveX);
    }
    return resultingCombinations;
}

private static void emptySet(Set<Set<Integer>> resultingCombinations) {
    resultingCombinations.add(new HashSet<Integer>());
}

private static Integer popLast(List<Integer> elementsExclusiveX) {
    return elementsExclusiveX.remove(elementsExclusiveX.size()-1);
}
```

Edit: Made some minor changes for readability

Comment: Is there a way it can be done without <Set> ?

Comment: You could substitute Set<Set<Integer>> with List<List<Integer>> if you adjust the methods.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment add: "as long as you guarantee, that every element in the list is unique(the behaviour of set does that). To experiment, i reccomend to open up your favourite IDE and make a search&replace for "Set<Set<Integer>>" with "List<List<Integer>>"